# How to set div width based on a set of dynamic images?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html

I have a set of 15 images that are stacked horizontally. They are completely dynamic in size based on the viewport size.

To extend the page past 100% I'm using a DIV which needs to have it's width updated periodically with the widths of the 15 images + a fixed amount.

I'm fairly new to javascript but I looked around and was able to peice together a simple script and made a test page.

**Update, here's the full code of the test page which I can't get to work:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onresize = function(event) { 
var img = document.getElementById('1');   
var w1 = parseInt(img.clientWidth);  
var img = document.getElementById('2');   
var w2 = parseInt(img.clientWidth);  

d.style.width= w1 + w2 + 400;  
} 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.gal{
  vertical-align:middle;      
} 
</style>
</head>

<body style="color: #1b1b1d">
<div style="position:absolute; width:18500px; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; left:0px; right:0px;z-index:1;background-color:#1b1b1d">
<img id="1" class="gal" height="100%" src="image1.jpg" />&nbsp;
<img id="2" class="gal" height="100%" style="max-height:652px;max-width:1024px" src="image1.jpg" />&nbsp;
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

It fails to work both with and without + "px" at the end of the script.

For whatever reason it's not working at all. Can anyone help guide me here? I'm new to this. I have jquery installed with another copy and pasted script if that helps.

Comment: "w1 + w2 + 400" equals "w1 + w2 + 400", not w1 + w2 + 400.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, your nick fits well to your comment :-)

Comment: Since when can [ids](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) contain the `#` character? Please write correct HTML.

Comment: I've had some more success with the script but for some reason it only takes the dimensions of the LAST image and sets all the variables equal to that. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('#1');  
var w1 = img.clientWidth; 
var img = document.getElementById('#2');  
var w2 = img.clientWidth; 

d.style.width = (w1 + w2 + 400) + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('1');  
var w1 = parseInt(img.clientWidth); 
var img = document.getElementById('2');  
var w2 = parseInt(img.clientWidth); 

d.style.width= (w1 + w2 + 400) + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the last line in your script:

```
d.style.width="w1 + w2 + 400";
```

Needs to not be in quotes ie:

```
d.style.width= w1 + w2 + 400;
```

With regards to updating the width dynamically - you would really need to attach this script to the resize event of the browser to handle it. ie:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    //your code here
}
```